# How to pass Unix output into progress code as variable

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

For ex:

```
Def var l_output as character.

Unix silent value(file filename | awk '{print $2}').
```

Output will be like format of filename i.e ascii, so now I need to return this value in a variable l_output??

Pls someone help me to sort this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `INPUT THROUGH VALUE (your Unix statement).`

This opens a stream for the output of the OS Command. Then

```
REPEAT:
  IMPORT l_output.
  MESSAGE l_output.
END.
```